# Django Calculate Mean Of 2 Fields Inside Multiple Objects

Tags: django, math, django-models, django-views, aggregate

I'm trying to do a very simple math problem but I don't know how to convert it into python. Basically I need to calculate the mean entry price for a trade based on multiple "buy" entries. To do that all one needs to do is calculate

```
∑ (entry.amount * entry.price) / ∑ (entry.amount)
```

This should be the variable "total_entry_price2" in the end.

1. Where am I going wrong with the calculation? How Can I add all the ∑'s together?
2. Is this the best way to do it?

models.py

```
class Trade(models.Model):
    ... 

class Entry(models.Model):
    ...
    trade = models.ForeignKey(Trade, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    entry_type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=ENTRY_TYPE_CHOICES, default=BUY)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def trade_detail_view(request, pk):
    logger.info('trade detail view')
    if request.method == 'GET':
        trade = get_object_or_404(Trade, pk=pk)
        entries = Entry.objects.filter(trade=trade)
        entries_buy = Entry.objects.filter(trade=trade, entry_type="buy")
        patterns = Pattern.objects.filter(trade=trade)

        for entry in entries_buy:
            total_entry_price = Sum(entry.amount * entry.price)
            total_entry_price2 = total_entry_price / entries_buy.aggregate(Sum('amount'))
            print(total_entry_price2)

        context = {
            'trade': trade,
            'entries': entries,
            'patterns': patterns,
            'max_amount': entries_buy.aggregate(Sum('amount')),
            'total_fees': entries.aggregate(Sum('fee')),
            'entry_price': entries_buy.aggregate(Avg('price'))
        }
```

Current Terminal print:

```
Sum(Value(60.0)) / Value({'amount__sum': 40.0})
Sum(Value(10.0)) / Value({'amount__sum': 40.0})
```

Example data

[image]

**The correct answer should be $1.75**

```
(30 * 2 + 10 * 1) / 40 = 1.75
```

---

**Final Solution (added upon from Oleg Russkin's Answer)**

The revisions I did are as follows:

```
total_entry_cost = entries_buy.annotate(
    s=F('amount') * F('price')
).aggregate(
    total_entry_cost=ExpressionWrapper(
        Sum(
            Cast('s', output_field=models.FloatField())
        ) / Sum('amount'),
        output_field=models.FloatField()
    )
)['total_entry_cost']
print(total_entry_cost)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example query to calculate required value.

`Cast()` to float may be avoided if the result of `Sum` is float, not an `integer`.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, F, Sum
from django.db.models.functions import Cast


total_entry_price2 = Entry.objects.annotate(
    s=F('amount')+F('price')
).aggregate(
    price2=ExpressionWrapper(
        Sum(
            Cast('s',output_field=models.FloatField())
        ) / Sum('amount'),
        output_field=models.FloatField()
    )
)['price2']

# Actual result of the query is dictioanry
# so we get the key
# {'price2': 0.59633706227207}
```

---

Updated Answer By OP

This answer almost got us all the way. It was my fault not to be more clear on the exact answer I was looking for. I updated my question near the end to reflect it.

The revisions I did are as follows:

```
total_entry_cost = entries_buy.annotate(
    s=F('amount') * F('price')
).aggregate(
    total_entry_cost=ExpressionWrapper(
        Sum(
            Cast('s', output_field=models.FloatField())
        ) / Sum('amount'),
        output_field=models.FloatField()
    )
)['total_entry_cost']
print(total_entry_cost)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to implement that right now. The only issue is the actual result. I went ahead and updated the question at the end to include the correct result I am looking for. I apologize that I was not clear enough here. A key part is to only use entries that are entry_type="buy"

Comment: Your foundation worked! Just needed to make some small edits to reflect only "entries_buy"